# Trying to click and select dropdown menu with Capybara

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

Trying to click and select dropdown menu with Capybara. But the dropdown is dynamic and doesn't have hard-coded options. And so far in my attempts I haven't been able to select any options from it. I'm trying to select the first or second value in the dropdown.  The HTML is:

```
<span class="dojoComboBoxOuter dj_gecko" _="whitespace and CR's between tags adds   in FF" style="width: 400px;">

<input dojoattachpoint="comboBoxValue" value="" name="personSelect" tabindex="-1" style="display:none"></input>
<input dojoattachpoint="comboBoxSelectionValue" value="" name="personSelect_selected" tabindex="-1" style="display:none"></input>
<input class="dojoComboBox" type="text" dojoattachpoint="textInputNode" dojoattachevent="key:_handleKeyEvents; keyUp: onKeyUp; compositionEnd; onResize;" autocomplete="off" style="width: 400px;"></input>
<img class="dojoComboBox" vspace="0" hspace="0" src="/ess/assets/static/dojo-0.4.3-custom-4.1.6/src/widget/templates/images/combo_box_arrow.png" dojoattachevent="onMouseUp: handleArrowClick; onResize;" dojoattachpoint="downArrowNode" style="width: 14px; height: 14px;"></img>

</span>
```

The little arrow for the dropdown is the last img class, it is called "combo_box_arrow.png", tried to select that but no luck.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know capybara but a general idea would be to click on the drop down image and then find all the input elements under the combo box and select the one you want to select. This is how I would do this in Java. I am sure you can reuse the css selectors for finding elements in capybara.

```
WebElement drop_down_image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.dojoComboBox"));
drop_down_image.click();
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.dojoComboBoxOuter>input[name^='personSelect']"));

for(WebElement option:options) {
      if(option.getText().equals("Drop down I want to select")) {
          option.click();
          break;
      }   
}
```

Please note, I wrote this code directly in the editor here, so there may be compilation errors, but you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Capybara won't (by default) let you interact with hidden elements, so you'd need to click the image and then interact with the inputs.  Something like this:

```
When /^(?:|I )choose the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) item from the dropdown"$/ do |position|
  position = position.to_i - 1
  within '.dojoComboBoxOuter' do
    all('input').at(position).click
  end
end
```